# How do I change train direction?

Tags: mini-metro

I have two circular lines two trains each. One line has trains run in both directions, but another one is counterclockwise for both trains. It sucks because of the shape order I case in my case. How do switch the train direction?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Grab the train and move slowly between two stations -- you'll see when the train is closer to one of stations it reorients to it.